# How to focus element in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using Protractor for automation. There is a page in an application where there is one web element `button` which Protractor can not find while execution. That web element is present in DOM but it is not visible on screen. Protractor is able to find & click the element only when we scroll down in application. But this is not a good approach as every time I have to place the code of page_Down.

Any help here ?

Comment: That's desired behaviour. Protractor behaves like a user. A user can't press a button, that is out of sight .
There is an option to scroll down until an element is visible. Try with that.

Comment: @ErnstZwingli: Thanks for letting me know. You suggested that there is option to scroll down until an element is visible. Could you please let me know about this option.

Comment: Sudharsan Selvaraj described it in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `ele.scrollIntoView(true)` method to make an element visible in view port.

```
var button = element(by.buttonText("Login"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",button.getWebELement()):
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button),5000);
button.click();
```

[Here you find the JavaScript definition of `scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: I faced synchronization issues, this worked for me: browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button),5000).then(()=>{ browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",button.getWebElement());
; });